# understanding count the number of occurrences of a pattern in a string

Tags: r, string, dataframe, tidyverse

my input:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)
tdf<-data.frame("foo"=c('|ReviewNG-BB.2|ReviewNG-BB.3','|ReviewNG-BB.2|ReviewNG-BB.3','|ReviewNG-BB.2|ReviewNG-BB.3','|ReviewNG-BB.2|ReviewNG-BB.3','|ReviewNG-BB.2|ReviewNG-BB.3','|ReviewNG-BB.2|NG-BB.3','|ReviewNG-BB.2|NG-BB.3','|ReviewNG-BB.2|NG-BB.3','|ReviewNG-BB.2|NG-BB.3','|ReviewNG-BB.2|NG-BB.3','|ReviewNG-BB.2|NG-BB.3','|TI'), 
"bar"=c('|AI|BB.2','|AI|BB.2','|AI|BB.2','|AI|BB.2','|AI|BB.2','|AI|BB.2','|AI|BB.2','|AI|ReviewNG-BB.2','|AI|ReviewNG-BB.2','|AI|ReviewNG-BB.2','|AI|ReviewNG-BB.2','|AI'), 
                 "xyz" = c('|ICV|NG-AI','|ICV|NG-AI','|ICV|NG-AI','|ICV|NG-AI','|ICV|NG-AI','|ICV|NG-AI','|ICV|NG-AI','|ReviewNG-ICV|TI|BB.2',
'|ReviewNG-ICV|TI|BB.2','|ReviewNG-ICV|TI|BB.2','|ReviewNG-ICV|TI|BB.2','|ICV'),
                 "gaz" = c('|BB.3|ReviewNG-AI|NG-TI','|BB.3|ReviewNG-AI|NG-TI','|BB.3|ReviewNG-AI|NG-TI','|BB.3|ReviewNG-AI|NG-TI',
'|BB.3|ReviewNG-AI|NG-TI','|BB.3|ReviewNG-AI|NG-TI','|BB.3|ReviewNG-AI|NG-TI','|NG-BB.2|ICV|AI|TI','|NG-BB.2|ICV|AI|TI','|NG-BB.2|ICV|AI|TI',
'|NG-BB.2|ICV|AI|TI','|BB.2'))
```

I trying count the number of occurrences of each label in my `tdf`, all label have 4 "form": Total count of occurences, `ReviewNG-label`, `NG-label` and at least "pure" `|label, |label|`. For example label `AI`, have all matches total, have `ReviewNG-AI`, `NG-AI`, and `|AI` or `|AI|` pure form. So that my code:

```
pt_t <- c("AI" )
sum(stringi::stri_count_fixed(tdf, regex(pt_t)))
pt_rng <- c("ReviewNG-AI")
sum(stringi::stri_count_fixed(tdf, regex(pt_rng)))
pt_ng<-c("NG-AI")
sum(stringi::stri_count_fixed(tdf, regex(pt_ng)))
pt<-c("|AI","|AI|")
sum(stringi::stri_count_fixed(tdf, regex(pt)))
```

And my output:

```
Warning in stringi::stri_count_fixed(tdf, regex(pt_t)) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
[1] 30
Warning in stringi::stri_count_fixed(tdf, regex(pt_rng)) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
[1] 7
Warning in stringi::stri_count_fixed(tdf, regex(pt_ng)) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
[1] 14
Warning in stringi::stri_count_fixed(tdf, regex(pt)) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
[1] 15
```

First of all, I don't exactly understand at warning message.
Now let's look a count: For total it's Ok, for `ReviewNG-AI` stil good. But next a problematic:
for `NG-AI` I understand is double count `NG` plus `ReviewNG`, and last "pure" count for `|AI' or '|AI|` I totally don't understand how it equally 15, where manually I count 16.

I also trying `stringr` in `tidyverse` but here really erroneous output:

```
sum(str_count(tdf,pt))

res<-tdf %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(),
                   ~sum(str_count(.x, paste(pt)))))

rowSums(res)
```

Comment: Is each label separated by `|` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is using an special character in RegEx: `|` is reserved for `or` in RegEx. If we want to search for `|` we need to escape with `\\|`. So, for example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

pt <- c("\\|AI", "\\|AI\\|")
```

Now, we want to count every occurence of `|AI` *and* `|AI|`, so the search pattern looks like this:

```r
paste(pt, collapse = "|")
#> [1] "\\|AI|\\|AI\\|"
```

So, putting it all together:

```r
tdf %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(),
                   ~sum(str_count(.x, paste(pt, collapse = "|")))))
```

returns

```r
  foo bar xyz gaz
1   0  12   0   4
```

Comment: there is one more problem if label have problems(for example `Out PPS`) the counting is not correct

Comment: Can you please clarify the problem? What do you mean with `Out PPS`? Where does the error occure and what do you expect as output?

Comment: I am sorry, my fault I use `//` instead `\\`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this kind of solution. As Martin already explained why and how we could do a different strategy.
If all Labels are separated by `|`

we could `pivot_longer` and `count` them. Depending on your desired output:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tdf %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    everything()
  ) %>% 
  mutate(value = sub('\\|', '', value)) %>% 
  separate_rows(value, sep = "\\|") %>% 
  group_by(name, value) %>% 
  summarise(Labels = n())
```

```
   name  value         Labels
   <chr> <chr>          <int>
 1 bar   AI                12
 2 bar   BB.2               7
 3 bar   ReviewNG-BB.2      4
 4 foo   NG-BB.3            6
 5 foo   ReviewNG-BB.2     11
 6 foo   ReviewNG-BB.3      5
 7 foo   TI                 1
 8 gaz   AI                 4
 9 gaz   BB.2               1
10 gaz   BB.3               7
11 gaz   ICV                4
12 gaz   NG-BB.2            4
13 gaz   NG-TI              7
14 gaz   ReviewNG-AI        7
15 gaz   TI                 4
16 xyz   BB.2               4
17 xyz   ICV                8
18 xyz   NG-AI              7
19 xyz   ReviewNG-ICV       4
20 xyz   TI                 4
```

Comment: the problem in my df 80+ columns